# in what situation does the HTTP_REFERER not work?

Tags: http-referer

I have used referrer before in foo.php to decide whether the page iframing foo.php is of a particular URL.  (using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`)

It turned out that most of the time, it worked (about 98% of the time), but it also seemed like some users arrived the page and `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` was not set in foo.php and therefore broke the code.  [**update**: These user claimed that they followed the usual page flow and didn't use the URL of foo.php all by itself on the browser (that they let it be an iframe) and the users never altered their browser settings.]

I wonder what the reasons are that it could happen?

Answer (score 6):

The [HTTP/1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) does not make it mandatory to send an HTTP referer header. You can't make any assumptions about its presence when writing robust code; perfectly conforment browsers may not include it.

Moreoever, the RFC advises that *"The Referer field MUST NOT be sent if the Request-URI was obtained from a source that does not have its own URI, such as input from the user keyboard"*, and *"We suggest, though do not require, that a convenient toggle interface be provided for the user to enable or disable the sending of From and Referer information"*.

The later is not very common (though some browsers have a "Private" mode that fulfils the requirements). More likely for your 2% is that people Bookmarked the URL, which fulfils the first criteria (URI obtained from a source without a URI), and so the browser sends no referer.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default AFAIK, but it's easy to turn it off (for privacy) e.g. in Firefox via about:config, and surely some users could be using browsers distributed to them (e.g. by their IT department) with such kinds of setting. So you should try to avoid relying on REFERER for any important functionality (also because it's mis-spelled, of course;-).