# Restrict my api not to be used by un-authorised websites

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, codeigniter-3

I'M beginner to `REST API` creation.
I have created a `REST AP`I (provides JSON output) which I give access to multiple users(each has their `API key)`.

I want each user can only use the API on a specific website, not for other websites.

Example:

> User-A (with unique API key) took my API for "example1.com".
>
> User-B (with unique API key) took my API for "example2.com".

so my API should run on these 2 sites, they can not run it in "example3.com".

How can I restrict them?

Comment: You can restrict the access via IP.

Comment: If you restrict access via IP, can happen that same IP is shared among different websites.
Maybe this could be useful for your needs:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140504/restricting-access-to-rest-api

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the answer. but how can I get IP of the website from where the CURL is being called..?  I am trying with   $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; this one which is not solving my problem..

Answer (score 0):

For what u want to accomplish take a look at [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) Here another [post](https://enable-cors.org/) on it

Basically in server side (PHP)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
```

In Your case u can do something like:

```
$http_origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
if ($http_origin == "http://www.domain1.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain2.com" || $http_origin == "http://www.domain3.info")
{  
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin");
}
```

For more resources take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

DISCLAIMER FROM CODE PART: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454204/1027877

Comment: HTTP_ORIGIN dont work for me... throughing error.A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: HTTP_ORIGIN

Comment: Even I tried with http_referer  but dont work, the API users send data using CURL..